# How does the IPSec Key Exchange protocol work?

Tags: cryptography, md5, ipsec, diffie-hellman

I need to fully understand the IPSec Phase 1 negotiation.
now, I break this to 3 steps:

1. Algorithm negotiations
2. Key Exchange Data
3. Identification

I'm using Wireshark to investigate the process and so far I fully understand the first part (Algorithm Negotiations).

My current problem lies in the 2nd part: Key Exchange Data.

The algorithms in use are AES-CBC-256bit, Pre-shared key, MD5 & 1024 bit Group.

The "ISAKMP Payload"->"KeyExchange Payload"->"KeyExchangeData" is beyond me...
I have no clue what it is.. an MD5'ed pre-shared key? Is it encrypted?

Comment: Which description are you looking at? Are you familiar with Diffie-Hellman key exchange?

Comment: IPSec is easy to figure out. Women, now that's hard!

Comment: I wrote the D-H algorithm from scratch, so I belive i do know it, but what I am tring to do is building a complete IPSec suit, i have a costum unix OS which is being used as my platform

Comment: @John: Is this still an open question? If you did find a solution yourself, could you add it as an answer here?

Answer (score 1):

See [draft-kivinen-ipsecme-ikev2-minimal-01](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kivinen-ipsecme-ikev2-minimal-01). It does a pretty good job explaining on what is needed for IKEv2 protocol

ISAKMP / IKEv1 / IPSec phase 1 is a bit more complicated, but most things in IKEv2 are somewhat analogous to the older version - and certainly help in learning the more complex stuff.

Key exchange data in the `KE` payload is just the Diffie-Hellman "shared secret". If you are literate with python code, see [this project](https://github.com/kimvais/pyike/blob/master/payloads.py). There is also a [module](https://github.com/kimvais/pyike/blob/master/util/dh.py) that can do the math and has some of the most used DH group's primes.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/iguide-ipsec.html) should help to understand IPSec.

Comment: m.. that was sort of a summary for what i know...
i need it more on the porgramming side... it's kind of a task I need to do in order to get my P.E. diploma, well, it's part of my task at least...